# JQuery won't select appended hidden element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dynamically adding elements:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    success:function(data) {
        $('#trNew').before( data );
    }
});
```

and `data`:

```
<tr id="val1">
    <td>...</td>
    <td><a id="e1" href="#" onclick="return editRow('e1')">Edit</a></td>
    <div class="hide" id="popup1">
        <input type="text">
        <button>Save</button>
    </div> 
</tr>
```

is inserted in the proper place. However, in `editRow()` (which gets invoked properly) when I try to select `$("#popup18")` or `$("#popup18:hidden")`, nothing gets selected. `document.getElementById("popup1")` also returns undefined.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: can you provide a jsFiddle page for your question?

Comment: Your html is invalid. Make it valid by moving the div to td

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, the `tr` does not support `divs` as children

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element

> Zero or more td, th, and script-supporting elements

so thats basicly invalid html - therefor nothing or everything may work - depends on how the stars are aligned today

Comment: Thanks. What confused me in the first place was that I was using the same php code to load some static elements, and now that I have 'inspected' elements more closely, I found that whatever is responsible for creating the DOM tree moved those `div`s to parent div, thus making the markup valid.

Answer (score 2):

thisTry to change the line in html, like this:

```
 <td><a id="e1" href="#" onclick="return editRow(this)">Edit</a></td>
```

I have changed the editRow(this) from editRow('e1').
 This will pass the anchor element as object.

And change your Html lik:

```
<tr id="val1">
    <td>...</td>
    <td><a id="e1" href="#" onclick="return editRow(this)">Edit</a>
        <div class="hide" id="popup1">
           <input type="text">
           <button>Save</button>
        </div> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

You can try this working on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/ELK8c/

Comment: Thanks. I would accept your answer, but the one above beat you by 20 secs and is more useful for future generations. :)

Comment: Sorry! I am not playing any game. I just try to help so that I could be helped by someone in the future :-)